# Decoupling software components via naming convention

Tags: java, c#, architecture

I'm currently evaluating alternatives to refactor a drivermanagement.

In my multitier architecture I have

Baseclass

- `DAL.Device` //my entity

Interfaces

- `BL.IDriver` //handles the dataprocessing between application and device
- `BL.IDriverCreator` //creates an `IDriver` from a `Device`
- `BL.IDriverFactory` //handles the driver creation requests

Every specialization of `Device` has a corresponding `IDriver` implementation and a corresponding `IDriverCreator` implementation.

At the moment the mapping is fix via a type check within the business layer / `DriverFactory`. That means every new driver needs a) changing code within the `DriverFactory` and b) referencing the new `IDriver` implementation / assembly. On a customers point of view that means, every new driver, used or not, needs a complex revalidation of their hardware environment, because it's a critical process.

My first inspiration was to use a caliburn micro like nameconvention

see [Caliburn.Micro: Xaml Made Easy](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View%2FViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions)

- `BL.RestDriver`
- `BL.RestDriverCreator`
- `DAL.RestDevice`

After receiving the `RestDevice`within the `IDriverFactory` I can load all driver dlls via reflection and do a namesplitting/comparing (extracting the xx from xxDriverCreator and xxDevice)

Another idea would be a custom attribute (which also leads to comparing strings).

My question: is that a good approach above layer borders? If not, what would be a good approach?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your situation. However, would a prototype pattern work? Your factory gets populated by a customer specific top-level app/class and the factory simply clones the requested driver instances without regards to its specific type. It still means having to do the same thing as new drivers are added, but changes occur in a different place and only customers that care about the new driver would be affected. Plus, I think this removes the changes from the "critical process" into another module which will help alleviate some of the required validation.

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by "a good approach?"  Hopefully you don't mean "the most popular one" or "the one with the most thumbs up by avid programmers."

Comment: @Dunk: Now I'm not sure if I totally understand :) using a prototype pattern would not solve the problem with mapping the concrete `RestDevice` which comes from the Client into a concrete `RestDriver` (which is the same for all customers) within the businesslayer. The critical process is not the adding of a new driver. It's the customers production process. If they have changes on used components (the driverfactory, as it hardcoded maps the drivers and has to be extended) they have to revalidate their complete hardware environment, which can last up to one week.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As my first language is not english, I actually meant "Is it a acceptable solution within a multitier application" (especially to specify namingconventions above borders e.g. DAL > Client > SL/BL )

Comment: "Acceptable" is just a substitute word for "good."  When you ask questions on an SE site, it helps if we can understand your *criteria* for what you consider acceptable.  Otherwise, it's just our opinion, man.

Comment: @cstein:If the driverfactory is a class (which I think it is from your description) then the goal is to make sure it doesn't change. In particular, make sure it doesn't change unless the customer wants it to change. Using the prototype pattern accomplishes this. The data stored in the driverfactory will change, but the driverfactory class itself will likely never need to change once it is written. You can populate the class in many different ways but the goal would be not to populate it with new drivers if the customer doesn't want it. Thus, script/config files sounds like the way to go...

Comment: ...each customer would create their own custom script file that is read by your app and creates the device instances that the customer uses and these get added to the driverfactory. Then, when the customer wants a specific device it asks for it from the factory and the device gets cloned (and optionally populated with initial configuration data) by the factory and returned. The key behind using the script files is that one customer can add drivers without forcing retesting upon other customers. Or, it is likely that I still don't understand the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you can get around the dependency on a common interface for plugins (IDriver in this example). Maybe I am not understanding that right. Anyway, naming convention is the preferred and modern way of structuring software over convention. Asp.net itself uses the pattern.

You may want to include a tool to validate the assemblies to make sure they comply with the convention, but otherwise I say go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Relying on naming convention for creating plugin mechanism is a well known approach to avoid unnecessary boiler plate code and to follow the Open/Closed principle. However, the convention should be documented well, and you should take some precautions against typos - for example, if someone writes "Devices" or "Devce", make sure your driver manager will become aware of that and signal an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question specially aims a namingconvention above application borders (DAL > CLIENT > BL).

Answer (score 0):

I would choose a custom attribute over a naming convention. This is the method used in most reflection based API's in .net. It prevents mistakes caused by accidental name matches or mismatches.